# prove using natural deduction that $\forall x(P(x) \to P(x))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

My question is how how to start the initial assumption. I thought about starting the demonstration assuming $P(x_{0})$ and then use the universal generalization to deduce $\forall x P(x)$:

(1) $x_{0}$ $P(x_{0})$  supposition

(2) $P(x_{0})$  copy of (1)

(3) $P(x_{0}) \to P(x_{0})$  implication of (1) and (2)

(4) $\forall x (P(x) \to P(x))$  Universal generalization (1)-(3)

Comment: Universal Generalisation should produce a universal quantified statement.  $\forall x~\ldots$

Comment: It's true, I forgot the quantifier. I already corrected the error.

Comment: Using my own simplified version of FOL (the basis for my proof-checking software), it is a two-line proof:  1 P(x0) (Premise), 2 ALL(x):[P(x) => P(x)] (Conclusion, 1)  (reformatted here for plain text). Just key in the premise P(x0) to get line 1. Then click the Conclusion button to get line 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the very idea.   I prefer to add indentation to keep track of assumption scopes, and to place square braces around an introduced variable; but that's just style choice.

1. $\quad [x_0]$ by Assumption (Arbitrary variable)
2. $\qquad P(x_0)$ by Assumption
3. $\qquad P(x_0)$ by Reiteration (2)
4. $\quad P(x_0)\to P(x_0)$ by Conditional Introduction (2-3)
5. $ \forall x~(P(x)\to P(x))$ by Universal Introduction (1-4) (aka Generalisation)

Step three is *somewhat* redundant, as reiteration is *more usually* used when the repeated line isn't in *immediate* proximity.   However, there is nothing wrong with using it here.

Now, some systems combine a few of the steps, in which you get the much abreviated

1. $\quad [x_0]~ P(x_0)$ by Assumption (Arbitrary variable)
2. $\quad P(x_0)$ by Reiteration
3. $ \forall x~(P(x)\to P(x))$ by Universal Introduction (/ Generalisation)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted to be sure of the demonstration.